# How to change the value in a group of cells?

Tags: r

I'm wondering if it is possible to change the contents of multiple cells in a table using R?

Consider this example: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plufg.png)

I need to change the values 'Femini.' to 'Feminine'. The problem is that i have a great number of cells to change... Is there some command that help me doing this?

Thanks for the help,
Luís

Comment: Note that R and Rstudio are distinct pieces of software. I suspect your question is about R, not Rstudio. Please provide a [working example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), so we can help you out. Pictures of data are not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Say your dataframe is called df

```
df$Genre[df$Genre == 'Femini'] <- 'Feminine'
```

Comment: it says 'invalid factor level, NA generated' when i apply that comand :(

Comment: when you read the file, set stringsAsFactors=FALSE 
   read.csv("path/file.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)